# How to destroy a wxPython frame in unittest

Tags: python, wxpython, python-unittest

I'm running unittests on my wxPython GUI.  The tests work approximately as expected, except that the frames that I create don't go away.  By the end of my tests, I have 30 or more top level windows.  Here is my setUp and tearDown code:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.app = wx.App()
    self.frame = MyGridFrame()

def tearDown(self):
    self.frame.Destroy()
    for wind in wx.GetTopLevelWindows():
        wind.Destroy()
    self.app.Destroy()
```

I tried several different combinations of the four lines you see in my tearDown function, but they all have the same (lack of any) effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tearDown function that works correctly from the documentation:
https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/unittests/wtc.py

```
def tearDown(self):
    def _cleanup():
        for tlw in wx.GetTopLevelWindows():
            if tlw:
                tlw.Destroy()
        wx.WakeUpIdle()
        #self.app.ExitMainLoop()   
    wx.CallLater(50, _cleanup)
    self.app.MainLoop()
    del self.app
```

Presumably the event loop has to be running to actually catch and process the close event generated by calling window.Destroy().  It makes sense, but took me a while to figure out.

Comment: In many cases, Destroy does not actually act to delete the windows until AFTER all events are processed. So you need to run MainLoop() to ensure that all events are processed.